# Flask/ SQLAlchemy: iter query result only gets relationships if i previously print the query?

Tags: loops, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship

I do not understand whats goin on here:
I have got a SQLite-Table and SQLAlchemy on Flask.

```
class mymodel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"something('{self.id}')"

    def __iter__(self):
        values = vars(self)
        for attr in self.__mapper__.attrs.keys():
            if attr in values:
                yield attr, values[attr]

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content=db.relationship('mymodel', backref='creator', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"something_else('{self.id}','{self.title}')"

    def __iter__(self):
        values = vars(self)
        for attr in self.__mapper__.attrs.keys():
            if attr in values:
                yield attr, values[attr]
```

Then I query mymodel:

```
id=1
result=mymodel.query.filter(User.id==id).all()
for x,y in result:
    print(x,y)
```

The result is:

```
id 1
title mytitle
user_id 1
```

I would expect to have an object (from User) for user_id in return instead of the table value "1".
BUT if I repeat the my query with a previous print statement, the result is as expected:

```
id=1
result=mymodel.query.filter(User.id==id).all()
print(result)
for x,y in result:
    print(x,y)

The result is: 

id 1
title mytitle
user_id 1
content {'id':1,'title':'Username'}
```

I do not understand why the print-statement can change the results, I want to know why this happens and how I can control the results.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`lazy=True` makes the ORM only load the dependent when you access it. The for loop doesn't access it, but the `print(result)` does. It prints all the info. That makes the difference.